# Setting import path in an OPTIONS pragma

Tags: haskell, ghc, pragma

According to the [GHC 8.4.3 flag reference](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.3/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#finding-imports), the `-i` flag is *dynamic*, which means [it should be settable by an `OPTIONS` pragma](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.3/docs/html/users_guide/using.html#command-line-options-in-source-files).

So I tried the following:

```
.
├── Main.hs
└── imp
    └── Imported.hs
```

Contents of `imp/Imported.hs`:

```
module Imported (foo) where

foo :: String
foo = "Foo"
```

Contents of `Main.hs`:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -iimp #-}
import Imported (foo)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn foo
```

However, if I try to run `Main.hs` using `runhaskell`, it complains that `Imported` cannot be found:

```
$ runhaskell -v Main.hs
...
Main.hs:2:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Imported’
    Locations searched:
      Imported.hs
      Imported.lhs
      Imported.hsig
      Imported.lhsig
```

How do I specify the `-i` flag in an `OPTIONS` pragma?

Comment: hmm - I can replicate the behaviour. Would it be an option for you to use stack/cabal to specify the `include-dirs` (I guess not, just asking to make sure).

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: not really for my use case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a regression of a documentation bug that was [fixed](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1108) in 2007 and then re-broken in 2014 when a bunch of "static"s were changed to "dynamic"s in the flag reference table.  As per the linked bug report, the `-i` flag is not fully dynamic.  It can be `:set` in GHCi but can't be specified in an `OPTIONS_GHC` line.

Comment: Well that's a bummer.

Comment: Is there a ticket to fix the doc bug?